How do I view multiple lines in the Perseus Hopper?
How do I view multiple lines of a text from Perseus?
I attempted to load Mark 1.1-25 but if I put this into the search function the program crashes: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/invalidquery.jsp?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0155:book=Mark:chapter=1:verse=1-25 (archived)
What is the proper syntax/format for displaying/loading multiple lines within The Perseus Digital Library? Thank you so much for any help!

The search facility of Perseus Digital Library imposes quite a narrow format; it requires exactly as its own way of compilation of contents. Honestly, I sometimes find easier to locate the text via Web search engines appending the phrase 'Perseus Digital Library'.
As for larger chuncks of text, the following explanation is given (see The Perseus WWW Frequently Asked Questions List):

How can I download a complete text file?
Our copyright agreements with the publishers of our texts do not
permit us to offer full text downloading for all works in Perseus at
this time. Texts for which XML downloads are available are indicated
as such by a creative commons license and links to download options.
You will find these in the center of a text viewing page, below the
main focus text. We do not offer other formats for texts at this time.

Addendum
Upon the response from the site

No vocab found - try viewing the text at a broader level.

I've clicked on "broader level." For this text, it gives the whole chapter. Then, I've loaded vocabulary tool:


I was hoping to utilize the Vocab Tool on a chosen selection. It appears that this is not possible?

I've appended an addendum.
